# 'function' object is not an iterator

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def generator():
    yield 1
    yield 2
    yield 3
    yield 4
    
print(next(generator))
print(next(generator))
print(next(generator))
print(next(generator))
```

the error on vs is
print(next(generator))
TypeError: 'function' object is not an iterator

i think the output should be
1
2
3
4

so why this error happend ?

Comment: Because, as it says `generator` is a function, not an iterator. It is a generator function, so it *returns* an iterator (a generator)

Comment: "generator" is a generator function which **returns** a generator (also usable as iterator) when called.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The linked duplicate isn't the same question, but it will show you several proper examples of using a generator. Here's a quick hint, though: imagine if you had instead written `def generator(x):`. Where would you expect the value of `x` to come from? Another way you can understand how generators work is to try putting `python generator tutorial` [into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+generator+tutorial), or to read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#examples) (I admit the last part is hard to find).

Answer (score 1):

you defined 'generator' as a function that returns a generator you can call next on

```
def get_generator()
    yield 1
    yield 2

generator = get_generator()
first_value = next(generator)
print(first_value)
```

Answer (score 1):

Tru it with

```
generated = generator()
print(generated)
print(next(generated))
```

You need to call the method to start iterating it’s results

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct version:

```
def generator():
    yield 1
    yield 2
    yield 3
    yield 4

iterator = generator()

print(next(iterator))
print(next(iterator))
print(next(iterator))
print(next(iterator))
```

A function that contains `yield` statements is a *generator*. `next`, however, expects a *generator iterator*.

Generators **create** generator iterators.

For more information, look here for the difference between *generators* and *generator iterators*:
https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator

Comment: Yes, better. Normally I don't say anything, people use these terms differently from those definitions a lot, it was just that you went so strongly and explicitly against it :-)

Comment: No, please do say something :) I assume we're all here to learn, me included.